# Filter html table according to dropdown value

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I am currently using .NET Core and I am trying to filter my HTML table according to the dropdown value that I select. However, whenever I select a value, it just refreshes the page and set everything back to the original value.

JQuery code:

```
$(function() {
  $("dropdownFilter").change(function(e) {
    var myUrl = "/Home/Filter";
    var filter = JSON.stringify($("#dropdownFilter").val());

    $.ajax({
      type = "POST",
      url: myUrl,
      data: filter,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }).done(function(data) {
      window.location.href = data.newUrl;
    });
  });
});
```

CSHTML code:

```
<label for="dropdownFilter">Filter:</label>
<select id="dropdownFilter">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Controller code:

```
public JsonResult Filter([FromBody] string filterString){
    SampleModel sample = GetDataByFilter(filterString);
    return Json(new {newUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home", sample);
}
```

Comment: Can you write what value has newUrl? Does action HomeController.Index have a functionality of filtering?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to filter my HTML table according to the dropdown value that I select. However, whenever I select a value, it just refreshes the page and set everything back to the original value.

Based on the code you provided, in success callback function, the code snippet `window.location.href = data.newUrl` will do a redirection, which cause page refreshing.

If you'd like to filter HTML table according to the selected dropdown value on your javascript client side, you can try to make your API action `Filter([FromBody] string filterString)` return the filtered data `sample` instead of url info, so that in ajax success callback function you would get the filtered data then dynamically generate/repopulate html table to display the filtered data.